# generating dynamic docx documents

Tags: php, templates, docx

I'm looking for a way to generate docx-files using PHP.

I've used [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) but it's not sufficient for my project. It doesn't have enough elements and the template engine is too basic.

My system has to be capable of:

- nesting tables
- merging table cells
- looping templates
- combining/nesting templates

Are there any good solutions? Is there anyone with experience in this matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Also, take note that nesting tables is never a good idea, not even in Word.

Comment: It's not an opensource project but has a free version: http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/features

Have you tried it?

Comment: I've tried the free version, but it's only a basic version, without custom styles, simplified templates, etc..  So it's not really useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) can generate Docx documents in pure PHP, using the technique of templates.

- nesting tables => YES
- merging table cells => YES
- looping templates => I'm not sure what is means, but probably YES
- combining/nesting templates => You can insert XML sub templates, not DOCX sub-templates. Or you can read other DOCX sub-XML parts, and merge-them into a main DOCX.